# fopen() crashing on second use in c

Tags: c, fopen

for some reason, fopens keeps crashing in my program.

It works once when I am reading the input file and putting the contents into a variable. But for some reason, when I try to make it use fopens again, it crashes...

Could someone please help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *buf = "\0";
char buffer[99999] ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
ptr_file =fopen(inputFileLocation,"r");
    if (!ptr_file)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(buf,maxvalue, ptr_file)!=NULL)
    {
        strcat(buffer,buf);     
    }
    fclose(ptr_file);
... //workings
//then the program crashes if I add an fopen() and fclose() at the end

}
```

Comment: Post a minimal example that shows your problem and is compilable.  Nobody's going to be able to help if you can't show what's broken so far.

Comment: @joe there isnt that much to show, the program just crashes with no error message when include fopen() and fclose() in any capacity

Comment: show the code.  lots of people use fopen and fclose more than once with no problem, so the issue is likely in your usage.

Comment: Show an MCVE ([MCVE]).  That there isn't much code needed is good; that's a perfect MCVE.  But we need to see the code before we can guess how you're managing to write code that makes the program crash.

Comment: Memory corruption, apply `valgrind`, which will reveal that the problem is in some part of the code you haven't described.

Comment: Are you going to post the code that _doesn't_ work?

Comment: You are using `fgets` into a single character buffer (that might be read-only, but you are almost definitely overwriting other memory regardless).  Why aren't you using `fgets` directly into `buffer`?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I am only going to show the base code

Comment: @joe since I havent see that on any tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a pointer named buf that points to space containing a single character '\0'.
Then you use fgets() to try to read an unknown number of characters (you don't show what maxvalue is) into the space pointed to by buf. But that space is only one character long. Reading into it will overrun the space, causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer misses the point. It is not only about buffer overrun.
There is no buffer overrun for `maxvalue = 2;` yet the program will crash.

But step by step:

`fgets(buf, maxvalue, ptr_file) != NULL`

> The C library function `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)`
>   reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string
>   pointed to by `str`. It stops when either `(n-1)` characters are read, 
>   the `newline` character is read, or the `end-of-file` is reached,
>   whichever comes first. A `null` character is automatically appended in
>   str after the characters read to signal the end of the `C string`.

In your case `buf` is string literal of size `2`. This is quite likely too small for your needs.
But its not just about the size of `buf`!

**You cannot copy anything to the (constant) string literal!**  That operation crashes your program with signal `11` even if you read one character.

Constants refer to fixed values that the program may not alter during its execution. These fixed values are also called literals.

What you need is a `char array` of the proper size.

You could either declare it the same way as `char buffer[99999]`

```
// 1.
char buf[SIZE_OF_THE_BUF];  // remember that buf has to accept maxvalue-1 characters + `null` character
```

or dynamically allocate memory for it in the `main()`

```
//  2.a
char *buf;
// 
int main()
{
  // 2.b
  buf = malloc(maxvalue * sizeof(char));
 //...
}
```